# Unit of the Heaviside function

Tags: physics, dirac-delta

If a force $F_0$ acts on a movable particle for a short time, we get (setting integrations constants to 0)

$\ddot{x} = \frac{F_0}{m}\delta(t-t_0) \\
\dot{x} = \frac{F_0}{m}H(t-t_0)
$

So does the Heaviside function implicitly have the same unit as its argument or is this just wrong?

Comment: I suspect its units are idiosyncratic to each context it appears in. For instance, when we write $|x| = x(2H(x)-1)$, the subexpression $H(x)$ needs to be dimensionless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us first analyze the dimensions of the $\delta$-function.  From the definition of $\delta$-function

$$\int d\xi\,\delta(\xi) = 1.$$

For the dimensions of the LHS and RHS to be equal, there can only be two possibilities: (i) $ξ$ is dimensionless, in which case $δ(ξ)$ must also be dimensionless, or (ii) $ξ$ has dimensions, in which case $δ(ξ)$ must have dimensions of $ξ^{-1}$.

In your example, the argument of the delta function has dimensions of time, thus it would seem that your Eq. (i) has incorrect dimensions. One way to get around this issue is to assume that there is an imaginary "$1$" inside the delta function to fix the units, i.e., assume that

$$ δ(t-t_0) = \delta\left(\frac{t-t_0}{1 \text{ time unit}}\right).$$

If we use this definition, then $\delta(t)$ is dimensionless and Eq. (i) makes sense.  Now, the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) is defined by $$H(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \delta(\xi)\,d\xi.$$  For your example,

$$ H(t) = ∫_{-∞}^{t} ds\, \delta\left(\frac{s}{1 \text{ time unit}}\right) =  (1 \text{ time unit})\times \int_{-\infty}^{t/(1 \text{ time unit})} ds'\,\delta(s'),$$

which has dimensions of time, as the integral is completely dimensionless.  Thus, Eq. (ii) also makes sense once we assume the existence of an imaginary "$1$" with the correct units.

---

You could also assume that $F_0$ and $m$ have nonstandard dimensions so that $F_0/m$ has dimensions of $\text{time}^{-1}$ (e.g., assume that $F_0$ is an impulse instead of a force).  In this case, $\delta(t)$ would have dimensions of $\text{time}^{-1}$ and the Heaviside step function $H(t)$ would be dimensionless.

Comment: Thanks! In summary, I guess the answer is just "don't worry about it"

Comment: Worrying is sometimes good.  When I calculate something, the first thing I always try to see is if the result is dimensionally sound.  A good fraction of mistakes in early-stage calculations can be weeded out by analyzing dimensions.